# div position in masonry grid gallery in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating masonry grid gallery some thing like [this](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html). I am having issue to calculate div left and top position when "`position:absolute`" added. If there is no position absolute, I am getting top and left value. Please check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dw2GG/).
Here is my html code

here is my javascript code snippet

```
if(k<total){
   $(".sli1").each(function(){
// alert(k);
// var selectpos = selectedItems.position();
   var c = $(this).position();
   console.log(k + ':' + c.left);
   var d = $(this).outerWidth();
   $(this).css({"left": (c.left)});
// $(this).css({"position":"absolute"});
  });
}k++;
```

I want top and left position for each div. Can someone please help me? Thanks for advance.

Comment: can you show us your html

Comment: Here is live example http://jsfiddle.net/Dw2GG/